# How i can change size of a string array dynamically with functions? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, function

```cs
public static void aktar(string [] dizi)
{
  dizi = new string[5];
}

static void Main(string [] args)
{
  string [] dizi = new string[3];
  Console.WriteLine(dizi.Length);
  aktar(dizi);
  Console.WriteLine(dizi.Length);
  ...
```

I want the output to be:

```
3
5
```

but I'm getting the result:

```
3
3
```

How i can fix problem?

Comment: Even if the answer provided is on point, you really need to ask yourself if this kind of behavior is the one that you need (as your function creates a side-effect)

Comment: I think you may be better off with a `List<string>` e.g. `void aktar(List<string> dizi)
{
  dizi.Add("x");
  dizi.Add("y");
}
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use a `ref` parameter:

```
public static void aktar(ref string [] dizi)
{
    dizi = new string[5];
}
```

Then call it as:

```
...
aktar(ref dizi);
...
```

and it will pass a *reference* so it modifies the caller's version.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of information about the defaults of `C#` regarding reference and value types?

Answer (score 1):

## A. New array

`aktar` does not expand the array - it creates a new one.

```
public static void aktar(string [] dizi)
{
  dizi = new string[5];
}
```

You can use `ref` as `steve-friedl` suggested or return the new array:

```
public static string[] aktar(string [] dizi)
{
  return new string[5];
}
(...)
dizi = aktar(dizi);
```

Both approaches don't make a lot sense though as you loose the original data.

## B. Switch to `List<string>`

`List<T>` is ideal for storing data when the number of items may change.

```
public static void aktar(List<string> dizi)
{
  dizi.Add("x");
  dizi.Add("y");
}

static void Main(string [] args)
{
  var dizi = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
  Console.WriteLine(dizi.Count);
  aktar(dizi);
  Console.WriteLine(dizi.Count);
  ...
```

### `List` test

#### Code

```
public static void aktar(List<string> dizi)
{
  dizi.Add("x");
  dizi.Add("y");
}

static void Main(string [] args)
{
  var dizi = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
  Console.WriteLine(dizi.Count);
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", dizi));
  aktar(dizi);
  Console.WriteLine(dizi.Count);
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", dizi));
}
```

#### Output

```
3
a,b,c
5
a,b,c,x,y
```

Answer (score 0):

More casual solution for OOP world is to set your array as field or property, so it would be a reference:

```
string [] Dizi { get; set; }
```

So that you can create method

```
void aktar() {
  Dizi = new string[5];
}
```